# Cruzar dos Arreglos y sumar valores

Tags: javascript, array

solicito de su colaboración para que me indiquen por favor como puedo cruzar dos arreglos por un atributo y generar un tercer arreglo con los totales ejemplo:

```
estudiantes = [ {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Sebastián", email: "Sebastián@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "alexis", email: "alexis@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com"} ];

libros =[{email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 10}, 
         {email: "Sebastián@aol.com", libros: 5 }, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 3}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 0}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 32}, 
         {email: "alexis@aol.com", libros: 8}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 43}, 
         {email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 9}]
```

**Resultados esperado:**

```
librosEstudiantes = [{nombre: "Sebastián", email: "Sebastián@aol.com"}, 
                     {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com" , libros: 43}, 
                     {nombre: "alexis", email: "alexis@aol.com", libros: 8}, 
                     {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 5}, 
                     {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 47}, 
                     {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 11}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se podría hacer de diferentes formas , publicaré una . Los métodos más importantes para este ejemplo serán [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign) para copiar las propiedades en un solo objeto que posteriormente se evaluará. además de [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty) para saber si existe una propiedad en un Objeto. *(el código está comentado)*  Ojo : *(Se podría mejorar y optimizar más el código el cuál será su trabajo)*  :}

```js
estudiantes = [ {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Sebastián", email: "Sebastián@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "alexis", email: "alexis@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com"} ,
                {nombre: "Oscars", email: "Oscar@aoxl.com"} ];

libros =[{email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 10}, 
         {email: "Sebastián@aol.com", libros: 5 }, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 3}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 0}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 32}, 
         {email: "alexis@aol.com", libros: 8}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 43}, 
         {email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 9}] 



var librosEstudiantes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < estudiantes.length; i++) {
 // Variables temporales
 let total = 0;
 let isEquals= false;
 // Iteramos para sacar el total de libros
 // y almacenar en la variable total
 for (var j = 0; j < libros.length; j++) {
  if(estudiantes[i].email === libros[j].email ){
   total += parseInt(libros[j].libros);
   isEquals = true ; 
  }
 }

 //Sí es igual los emails , asignamos a temporal el objeto
 // del array estudiantes con index i 
 let temp = (isEquals) ? estudiantes[i] : [];
 // Verificamos  si el Objeto tiene una propiedad email.
 if(temp.hasOwnProperty('email')){
  let nuevo = Object.assign(estudiantes[i], temp);
  // Asignamos el nuevo total obtenido luego de iterar los valores.
  nuevo.libros = total;
  // variable temporal
  let existe = false;
  // Verificamos la existencia del elemento en el arreglo resultante
  for (var k = 0; k < librosEstudiantes.length && !existe ; k++) {
   if(librosEstudiantes[k].email === nuevo.email) existe = true;
  }
  // Sí no existe , añadimos el elemento
  if(!existe){
   librosEstudiantes.push(nuevo);
  }
 }
}




console.log(librosEstudiantes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes otra posible solución utilizando diferentes métodos del objeto `Array`.

Básicamente lo que hace el código es generar el array de resultado recorriendo con el método `reduce` el array `estudiantes`. En la función de este método primero se comprueba si el usuario se ha añadido ya al resultado y, si no es así, se añade calculando el total de libros recorriendo también con el método `reduce` el array `libros`:

```js
var estudiantes = [ {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Sebastián", email: "Sebastián@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Rafael", email: "Rafael@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "alexis", email: "alexis@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Juan", email: "Juan@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Raúl", email: "Raúl@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com"}, 
                {nombre: "Oscar", email: "Oscar@aol.com"} ];

var libros =[{email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 10}, 
         {email: "Sebastián@aol.com", libros: 5 }, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 3}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 0}, 
         {email: "Rafael@aol.com", libros: 32}, 
         {email: "alexis@aol.com", libros: 8}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Juan@aol.com", libros: 1}, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Raúl@aol.com", libros: 43}, 
         {email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 2}, 
         {email: "Oscar@aol.com", libros: 9}] ;
         
var result = estudiantes.reduce(function(prev, item){
  if (prev.every(x => x.email !== item.email)){
    prev.push({
      nombre: item.nombre,
      email: item.email,
      libros: libros.reduce((p, i) => p+= (i.email===item.email ? i.libros : 0), 0)
    });
  }
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```